# Cannot load any datasets from tf.keras, gives error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

OS: Windows 10
tensorflow and keras succesfully imported, python 3.7.9

```
tf.__version__
>>> '2.1.0'
keras.__version__
>>> '2.2.4-tf'
```

### Problem

Tried load_datasets or any dataset available in tf.keras such as:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

give this error

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
.
.
.
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
.
.
.
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels- 
 idx1-ubyte.gz: None -- [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The three dots showing bunch of code lines that can't be executed.

Anyone knows how to solve? I've been looking for possible solutions but the closest I can find is solving certification/verification issue, I think mine is about URL.

I know the workaround is to download the dataset from kaggle etc., but I want to know what cause this. Thanks guys

EDIT: it's not URL problem, unable to access https://storage.googleapis.com using IDM, but files can be downloaded directly in browser. So I guess it's security issue

Answer (score 1):

Finally after 5 hours reading here and there..

Please check the solution by CRLannister here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33285

What it doesn't mention is where `data_utils.py` is located in case of Windows OS and anaconda environment. It's located here
`~\Anaconda3\envs\*your_env*\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py`

just add the following after all the import statement

```
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```